# writing to 2D array with {} and a number

Tags: arrays, visual-studio-2013

I would like to write the first part of an array with several variable then increment the position. All the variables are doubles with "j" being an int starting at 0. I know I could make another array with these values and use a loop to write them back, but if I could do something like this that would be much easier!

```
Sub storeValues(x, y, z, lnth, rotation, lift)
    store({x, y, z, lnth, rotation, lift}, j)
    j += 1
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the solution I came up with that I referenced in the OP. I think It's ok but I'd like to do what I originally wanted if that's possible.

```
Sub storeValues(x, y, z, lnth, rotation, lift)
    Dim Storetemp As Double() = {x, y, z, lnth, rotation, lift}
    For i = 0 To 5
        store(i, j) = Storetemp(i)
    Next
    j += 1
End Sub
```

Edit: 6 should have been a 5